# Automatically modify file lines depending on the git diff and searching a specific key word

Tags: bash

I have an issue where I have a lot of files modified with irrelevant changes.

All this changes have the same specific keyword in common.

Edit:I should do a script to modify the lines that contain that specific word. I need to read the git diff and depending on it modify the real file. I should not modify other lines though.

Code:

```
         variable="value"
-        pageid="id1">
+        pageid="id2"
+        variable2="value2"
+        variable3="value3">
```

What I don't want to commit is the change from id1 to id2, but the removal of that > should actually happen, so it should change to:

```
         variable="value"
-        pageid="id1">
+        pageid="id1"       //This is now id1, not id2
+        variable2="value2"
+        variable3="value3">
```

I'm not so comfortable with bash scripting. I can get to read the diffs but I don't really know how to extract the id1 and write it in place of id2...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What does Git itself have to do with your requirement?  That is, why not just handle this using some editing tool?

Comment: Because I have 1000+ files with those changes, doing it by hand is very time consuming. (Thanks for the interest).

Comment: Then write a bash script which updates all those files.  Git is not really a code editing tool, and while you _might_ be able to do this in a hook, it probably would be easier to not do that.

Comment: Humm, that makes a lot of sense. I'll look into how that script should be. Thanks.

Comment: Git [clean and smudge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_a) filters might help.

Comment: I realized it is slightly more difficult than I thought. I'll update the post.

As of now, I can check the diff with a script. I don't know how to update the file though... (working on it)

Comment: I do think you should rephrase your question and remove all the `git` references. This is not a `git` question but a refactoring topic that you might want to handle in a script or in the editor of your choice. If you do rewrite this and change tags you will most likely find help.